# Converting YYYYQQ to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have been trying to convert stuff like 2002Q3 to 2002-09-01, but if I use the following, it will convert 2002Q3 to 2002-07-01:

```
pd.PeriodIndex(['2002Q3], freq='Q').to_timestamp()
```

How can I get it to match to 2002-06-01, instead? For example, I want 2002Q1 to correspond to 2002-03-01, 2002Q2 to 2002-06-01, 2002Q3 to 2002-09-01, and 2002Q4 to 2002-12-01. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since your end goal is just `datetime64`, use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

- Given a Series of `YYYYQQ` strings:

  ```
  qtr = pd.Series([f'{y}Q{q}' for y in range(2000, 2010) for q in (1, 2, 3, 4)])

  # 0     2000Q1
  # 1     2000Q2
  # 2     2000Q3
  # 3     2000Q4
  # 4     2001Q1
  # ...
  # 38    2009Q3
  # 39    2009Q4
  # dtype: object
  ```
- [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) the `QQ` portion with your desired `-mm-dd` and convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

  ```
  mapping = {
      'Q1': '-03-01',
      'Q2': '-06-01',
      'Q3': '-09-01',
      'Q4': '-12-01',
  }
  pd.to_datetime(qtr.replace(mapping, regex=True))

  # 0    2000-03-01
  # 1    2000-06-01
  # 2    2000-09-01
  # 3    2000-12-01
  # 4    2001-03-01
  # ...         ...
  # 38   2009-09-01
  # 39   2009-12-01
  # dtype: datetime64[ns]
  ```